# Next.JS Static Generation not optimal for SEO when using `map` method

Tags: reactjs, static, next.js, seo, vercel

I am currently using `Next.JS` to create a `static website` with the main objective to have a very good SEO-optimized website.
Everything works fine and the website is correctly deployed with Vercel, but I have noticed that part of the content is not present directly in the `HTML` files.

For instance, I have a component that loops over an array of data, using the array `map` method, like this:

```
{imageTexts.map((image) => (
          <ImageText
            key={image.title + 'TitleImage'}
            title={image.title}
            description={image.description}
            size={imagesSize}
            image={image.image}
          />
        ))}
```

Once the website is deployed to `Vercel`, I search inside the `HTML` file for the information/strings contained in the array of data (`imageTexts`), but I can't find them. I guess Next.JS uses javascript to target some sort of `div` and then loops over its own JSON file to dynamically display content.

For me, this seems to kill a lot of the SEO advantage that `static websites` have over `SPA`. Is there any way I can have those strings directly inside my HTML files?
I am still not 100% sure this is caused by the `map` method, but I don't find any other explanations. Especially because other dynamically loaded components don't have the same problem. For example, this component string can be found on the `HTML` file, without a problem:

```
{title ? (
        <Text
          type="h2"
          textAlign="center"
        >
          {title}
        </Text>
      ) : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are mapping over `ImageTexts` on the server and that component renders HTML tags, then that HTML should be sent on the first-page load, and you could see it if you do CTRL+U or disable javascript.

Comment: I can't see the texts after doing a CTRL + U, that's the problem I am actually facing...
I have just checked your suggestion of disabling javascript and I found something interesting: I can see the images of the mapped object, but I can't see the strings. I will investigate further....

Comment: Ok, I just found out the reason... The texts/strings were inside a Component that interprets Markdown. Which is:

import { Remark } from 'react-remark'

Apparently, it does not play well with Next.JS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have just found that the reason. It has nothing to do with the `map` method. I was actually using the `<Remark>` component from library called `react-remark`. It seems it does not play well with Next.JS